# Is it possible to load dynamic data on load, and children on click without setting children inside parent state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got a fiddle, where I am loading dynamic data on load.
https://jsfiddle.net/61qxn7av/2/

Each parent should have different children - and the children should append to the correct parent(depending on which checkbox you click).

So is it possible to load children to the correct div, without having to set childData[] inside the parent? I am not sure if this is the way to go? It somehow feels wrong to send an empty child element to each parent whenever the data gets dynamic.

I mean can't you append the children somehow? Or whats the best practise to do something like this?

The specific code I would like to change:

```
var testData = [{
            "title": "Parent One",
            "id": 1,
            "childData": []
        },
```

Or should I load and show dynamic data on some other way?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to solve this. Seems like a basic solution.

1. Removed the childData array from the parent.

   ```
   var testData = [{
               "title": "Parent One",
               "id": 1
           },
   ```
2. Removed the parenthesis and added curly braces to the jsx method (so I could add a if check for null mapping):

   ```
   const ChildList = (props) => {
   var content = '';
       if (props.childData) {
       content = props.childData.map(item => <ChildComponent key={item.id} {...item} />);
       }
       return (
           <div>
             {content}
         </div>
       );
   };
   ```

New JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/0vhm8kxq/